# How to replace within string over loop of an replacer object?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input string and a replacement object, Now have to find occurrence of a text ( object key) separated by `=`  and want to replace with object values. but unable to find the solution.  Here is [my snippet](http://jsbin.com/kujeguhocu/edit?html,js,console) and the code is as follow.

```js
var replacer = function(tpl, data) {
  console.log('input==>', tpl);
  for(var key in data) {
    var re = new RegExp(key + '=(.*)', 'g');
    tpl = tpl.replace(re, function(match, p1, offset, string) {
      console.log('Replace=>', arguments);
      return p1; 
    });
    console.log('output==>', tpl);
  }
  console.log('final output==>', tpl);
};

var text = 'alpha=1\nbeta=2\nage=12\ncolor=green';

var result = replacer(text, { age: 15, color: 'red' });
```

input string : `'alpha=1\nbeta=2\nage=12\ncolor=green'`

replacer object : `{ age: 15, color: 'red' }`

desired output is : `'alpha=1\nbeta=2\nage=15\ncolor=red'`

---

#### Trial 1

use `return p1;`, then final output was ==> `'alpha=1\nbeta=2\n12\ngreen'`

#### Trial 2

use `return data[key];` than final output was ==> `'alpha=\nbeta=2\n15\nred'`

So What will be the right step to achieve the desire output ?

Comment: Your replacer function doesn't return anything

Comment: yes, but I have checked the final output `tpl` but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation of the code that also deals with those cases where `data[key]` is undefined. Note you do not need to use any capturing groups in the pattern, and thus you may shorten the list of arguments sent to the anonymous callback method:

```js
var replacer = function(tpl, data) {
  for(var key in data) {
    var re = new RegExp(key + '=.*', 'g');
    tpl = tpl.replace(re, data[key] ? key + '=' + data[key] : '$&');
  }
  return tpl;
};

var text = 'alpha=1\nbeta=2\nage=12\ncolor=green';
var result = replacer(text, { age: 15, color: 'red' });
console.log(result);
```

Another point: if you do not want to match `age` key in `mage`, you need to use

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + key + '=.*', 'g');
                     ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the `\b` tips. and yes this is better optiong using without capturing groups.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, you may get rid of the anonymous method since the arguments are no longer used. I updated the answer to make the solution more compact.

Comment: this is awesome, Kindly explain what and how `$&` work here?

Comment: `$&` is the backreference to the whole match value. When you had an anonymous callback method, you used `match` variable to refer to the whole match. When using string replacement patterns, the same is expressed with `$&` backreference. In the latest versions of Chrome and FF you can even use PCRE-like `$0`, but it does not work in IE for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement function has to return something to replace the entire match

```
return key+'='+data[key];
```

You also need to return tpl from your function

Comment: Yes, if `data[key]` is not undefined.

Comment: does this prevent unmatched data;

Comment: If you replace `return p1` in your existing code with Juan's code, the replacement is performed only for the specific key from the `for..in` loop. In which case key is sure to be a property of data and unmatched data shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also

```
var replacer = function(tpl, data) {
  console.log('input==>', tpl);
  for(var key in data) {
    var re = new RegExp(key + '=(.*)', 'g');
    tpl = tpl.replace(re, key+'='+data[key]);
  }
   console.log('final output==>', tpl);
};

var text = 'alpha=1\nbeta=2\nage=12\ncolor=green';

var result = replacer(text, { age: 15, color: 'red' });
```